# Anchor click - should not scroll to top

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net

I made a simple imagechanger:

```html
<a href="#" id="image<%# (Container.ItemIndex + 1)%>" onclick="document.getElementById('top_image').
src='<%= Application["AppPath"] %>/getImage.aspx?
name=<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "I_pathshort")%>&breite=349';">
```

works fine - but window automatic scroll to top - how can i fix this.

Comment: So ya, prevent default behaviour of anchor click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although i don't encourage the use of inline event, you can use `return false`

```
onclick="
    document.getElementById('top_image').src='your rendered SRC';
    return false;"
```